# Port Forwarding issue after Bridging

Tags: wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, bridge-router

TWC Roadrunner has provided us with Motorola SBG6580 Router/modem

I bought my own router Netgear WRN2000v2 running DD-WRT firmware..

i plan on using the netgear as my only router and dont wanna go through the hassle of forwarding ports on both router...

So I bridged the device as per the instructions provided on various sites [will edit the the link if i can find it back but till den heres a saved copy http://is.gd/E3amVj]

Now i cannot see my open ports that i have setup on the Netgear Router

on canyouseeme.org i get this error

```
Error: I could not see your service on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port (xxx)
Reason: Connection timed out
```

Comment: You bridged which device?  The Motorola, or the Netgear?

Comment: its Motorola > Netgear > PC/and  other devices over wifi

Comment: But which is now a bridge?

Comment: okay just checked windows now...... my comodo was port stealth was wrongly configured.... lol such a stupid reason i feel ashamed